# Do I have to work on Mac/OSX to be able to export a LibGDX app to iOS?

Tags: java, ios, macos, libgdx

I'm working with LibGDX 1.5.6 on Windows and had successfully exported my app to Desktop, Android and HTML5.

**But..**

Assuming that I had previously selected the iOS project when creating the Gradle projects in the libGDX setup. And that I have a registered Device, Developer License and Provisioning Certificates for iOS development.

**Is there a way to export my app to iOS, working on Windows?**

Comment: No, RoboVM compiling uses the Xcode installation.

Answer (score 0):

Since Robovm depends on XCode to be installed I don't think it would be possible to deploy to iOS within Windows.

See the prerequisites from the official libgdx documentation [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Deploying-your-application#deploy-to-ios).

However, I was able to do it by running a virtual machine with Mac OS X, but my experience with it was not very pleasant, it runs very slow, specially if you use the iOS simulator. You will need a machine with a lot of RAM (8 RAM minimum). So I ended up buying a Mac Mini.

I used to use VMWare Workstation for emulation, but I had to download patches to make it work on the latest OS X version since it is not supported officially. It is a little hard to find any Mac OS X images to install on a virtual machine. I do not have any links to OS X images since that was quite a while ago, but you might be able to find some.